# Python match regex always returning None

Tags: python, regex

I have a python regex that match method always return None. I tested in pythex site and the pattern seems OK.

[Pythex example](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C.aspx%5C?.%2acp=&test_string=page.aspx?cpm=549&cp=168&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

But when I try with re module, the result is always None:

```
import re
a = re.match(re.compile("\.aspx\?.*cp="), 'page.aspx?cpm=549&cp=168')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`re.match()` only matches at the *start* of a string. Use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead:

```
re.search(r"\.aspx\?.*cp=", 'page.aspx?cpm=549&cp=168')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"\.aspx\?.*cp=", 'page.aspx?cpm=549&cp=168')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105d7e440>
>>> re.search(r"\.aspx\?.*cp=", 'page.aspx?cpm=549&cp=168').group(0)
'.aspx?cpm=549&cp='
```

Note that any `re` functions that take a pattern, accept a string and will call `re.compile()` for you (which caches compilation results). You only need to use `re.compile()` if you want to store the compiled expression for re-use, at which point you can call `pattern.search()` on it:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\.aspx\?.*cp=")
pattern.search('page.aspx?cpm=549&cp=168')
```

Comment: I'm angry myself. =) I forgot the search method. Good observation, I'm storing the pattern for re-use.